# fGetCsv only reading first line?

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I'm trying to use fgetCsv but for some reason it is only reading the first line. Here is the code:

```
$fieldseparator = ",";
$lineseparator = "\r";


if(!file_exists($csvFile)) {
    echo "<div id='error'>Cannot find uploaded file. Please try again</div>";
    exit;
}

$file = fopen($csvFile,"r");

if(!$file) {
    echo "<div id='error'>Error loading CSV file</div>";
    exit;
}

$size = filesize($csvFile);
if(!$size) {
    echo "<div id='warning'>File is empty</div>";
    exit;
}

$query = "";
$content = fgetcsv($file,$size,$lineseparator);


fclose($file);

foreach($content as $data) {
        $values = explode($fieldseparator,$data);
        $query[$i] = "('".implode("','",$values)."')";
}
```

This just outputs one line. Here is the CSV file:

```
TSE-P01,1,WO47653897,RM,EcoQuiet,1
TSE-P02,1,WO47653898,RM,EcoQuiet,1
TSE-P03,1,WO47653899,RM,EcoQuiet,1
TSE-P04,1,WO47653900,RM,EcoQuiet,1
TSE-P05,1,WO47653901,RM,EcoQuiet,1
TSE-P06,1,WO47653902,RM,EcoQuiet,1
TSE-P07,1,WO47653903,RM,EcoQuiet,1
TSE-P08,1,WO47653904,RM,EcoQuiet,1
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php):

> fgetcsv — Gets **line** from file pointer and parse for CSV fields

If you want more than one line then you need to call it more than once.

Answer (score 10):

This example is the "Example 2" from w3schools http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fgetcsv.asp

```
$file = fopen("contacts.csv","r");

while(!feof($file))
  {
  print_r(fgetcsv($file));
  }

fclose($file);
```

Using the while loop the code iterates through the whole file/all the lines..

Alternatively.. if you do something like that..

```
print_r(fgetcsv($file));
print_r(fgetcsv($file));
print_r(fgetcsv($file));
```

It will print only the first 3 lines..